# Apollo not calling graphql query on load, vue.js, apollo

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to get data from a ruby server to a vue.js front end. I have set up Apollo like so

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});


const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
});


createApp({
  render: () => h(App),
})
  .use(apolloProvider)
  .mount("#app");
```

App.js

```
<script>


import AddVideoGame from "./components/AddVideoGame.vue";
import VideoGameList from "./components/VideoGameList.vue";

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {VideoGameList, AddVideoGame}
}

</script>

<template >
    <div id="app">
        <div class="title">
            Hello
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <!--        <CustomButton :on-click="consoleClick"/>-->
        </div>
        <add-video-game/>
        <video-game-list/>
    </div>
</template>
```

with the component that I added here:

```
<script>
import VideoGameItem from "./VideoGameItem.vue";
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import CustomButton from "./CustomButton.vue";

const GET_ALL_GAMES = gql`
    query query {
      videoGames {
        title
        platform
        rating
      }
    }
`;


export default {
    name: "VideoGameList",
    components: {CustomButton, VideoGameItem},
    data() {
        return {
            videoGames: []
        }
    },
    apollo: {
        videoGames: {
            query: GET_ALL_GAMES
        }
    }
};
</script>


<template>
    <div>
        <video-game-item v-for="videoGame in videoGame" :key="videoGame.id" :video-game="videoGame">{{videoGame.id}}</video-game-item>
        <CustomButton :on-click="consoleClick"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Right now the queries are not being executed and data not being set. I have already tried creating a local apolloProvidor for the component and was able to console.log the data needed. However I know that is not the preferred way of executing the query.

Also I know there is an issue with executing $apollo from an arrow function, but that is not what I am doing here.

Any help would be appreciated.